# Editar arquivo word .doc em Python

Tags: python-3.x, django, microsoft-word

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em `Python`e `Django` e preciso que o usuário anexe um arquivo de documento `.doc`. Feito isso, nesse aquivo, o usuário terá digitado algumas variáveis, e eu preciso substituí-las por informações do meu sistema.

Existe alguma ferramenta para poder editar documentos `.doc`em `Python`? Eu encontrei o `Python-docx`, mas parece que ele serve apenas para criar arquivos. Eu preciso abrir um documento e editar as informações.

Utilizo `Python 3.6`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na página inicial do `python-docx` diz:

> python-docx is a Python library for creating and **updating** Microsoft Word (.docx) files.

Na [documentação](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/document.html) menciona um construtor `Document` que retorna um objeto a partir e com isso você consegue trabalhar em cima do arquivo. Pelo que eu vi, o `python-docx` não tem nenhuma função `search` ou `replace`, então é necessário iterar sobre os objetos que o `Document` possui.

Por exemplo:

```
from docx import Document
document = Document('URL_PARA_SEU_ARQUIVO/Test.docx') 

for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
    if 'teste' in paragraph.text:
        print paragraph.text
        paragraph.text = 'novo texto teste'
```

No link da documentação que postei menciona esses objetos que você pode trabalhar.

Isso pode ajudar também: [How to use python-docx to replace text in a Word document and save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24805671/how-to-use-python-docx-to-replace-text-in-a-word-document-and-save)